# sms gateway using php and android phone

Tags: php, android, sms

i wonder how to make php application to send sms from android phone attached with usb to my pc.
I found some tutorials but they didn't work.
is there any  way to do it without any api and for free?

Comment: I wonder if its possible

Comment: do you think it is impossible?

Comment: You don't need USB for doing this, its just few hours of work with a server running on Android and a port listening to the request coming from outside.
The device must be connected to the Wifi with a static IP.
You can also make it work if you have a static public IP.
Look at my answer, it might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try [NanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) for Android. NanoHttpd will work as a server on Android.

Step 1:

Download the  [**NanoHTTPD.java**](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen/NanoHTTPD.java). Add this class in your project.

Create a Activity **(HttpServerConnection)** and add the following code:

```
public class HttpServerConnection extends Activity {

private WebServer server;
private static String TAG = "[HttpServerConnection]";
private static int default_server_port = 8005;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    // Init a server    
    server = new WebServer();
    try {
        server.start();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.w(TAG, "The server could not start.");
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.w(TAG, "================Web server initialized=============>");
}


// On destroy 
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (server != null) {
        server.stop();
        Log.w(TAG, "=================Web server stopped================>");
    }
}



// Webserver class which extends the NanoHTTPD class
private class WebServer extends NanoHTTPD {
    public WebServer() {
        super(default_server_port);
    }

    /*
     * Description : Function to run when a request message is triggered and
     * the application needs to process it to send a response.
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized Response serve(String uri, Method method,
            Map<String, String> header, Map<String, String> parameters,
            Map<String, String> files) {

        Log.w(TAG, "Request header details: " + header.toString());

        // Extract the parameters and header (mobile number and the message)

        // Send SMS using SmsManager

        return null;
    }
}

}
```

Step 2:
Push HTTP request from the php server to the NanoHttpd server with the parameters.

Step 3: 
The NanoHttpd server will receive the request in the function 'serve':

```
@Override
public synchronized Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {

}
```

Step 4:
Parse the data (Message and mobile number) from the request in the 'serve' function and send the SMS using the **SmsManager** class.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null,
                        null);
```

I have done a similar thing for my work (I have implemented it as a Android Service) and it works like a charm.
Its very easy to follow and the 'NanoHttpd' server is pretty stable to work with.

Comment: thank you for answer, but i am begginer and i don't understand anything after step 1. i setup nanohttpd server and what to do with this code

Comment: Edited my answer, have a look.